# php function to declare name and value of input field

Tags: php

I have some statements like

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from21' value='$_POST[from21]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from22' value='$_POST[from22]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from23' value='$_POST[from23]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from24' value='$_POST[from24]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from25' value='$_POST[from25]'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from26' value='$_POST[from26]'>";
```

I want to execute them through function like

```
function ddd($ed){
for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
{
echo "<input type='hidden' name='from.$ed.$i' value='$_POST[from.$ed.$i]'>";//-----------(1)
}
}
```

After that I will call the function like
    ddd('2');

But it is giving error. Must be some problem in (1). What should be the correct syntax.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: Just leave the dots away: `name='from$ed$i'`.

Comment: Variables do not work inside single quotes. Either double quote them or use `.` to concatenate them. So `name='from.$ed.$i'` becomes `name='from'.$ed.$i.'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

function ddd($ed){
    for ($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='from$ed$i' value='\$_POST[from$ed$i]'>";
    }
}

ddd('2');
```

The dollar sign in $_POST needed to be escaped with a backslash so you can echo it as is.
You also have to remove the dots between $ed and $i.

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/vJ8wlH).

Comment: You do not need to stop the string with `"`. Variables are parsed in double quotes: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `name='from.$ed.$i'`. You need to remove the dots or properly concatenate it to `name='from'.$ed.$i.'` as @aspirin says in the comment.